# Vuetify v-btn horizontal right

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to justity a v-btn to the right. I have tried everything and it's not working, I just want to know the easiest way to make the register button sit on the very right of the column.

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rexbrandy/pen/VwepMwj) and code.

```
<v-container>
    <v-row class='justify-center'>
      <v-col cols='6'>
        <v-form @submit.prevent='submitForm'>
          <v-text-field label='Username'></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field label='Password' type='password'></v-text-field>
          <v-btn type='submit' class='primary'>Login</v-btn>
          <v-btn class='ml-2'>Register</v-btn>
        </v-form>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```

Comment: Are you avoiding `<div>` for a specific reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to wrap those 2 buttons within a row first. Then put each one of them in a column as follows:

```
  <v-container>
    <v-row class='justify-center'>
      <v-col cols='6'>
        <v-form @submit.prevent='submitForm'>
          <v-text-field label='Username'></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field label='Password' type='password'></v-text-field>
          <v-row>
            <v-col xs="6">
               <v-btn type='submit' class='primary'>Login</v-btn>
            </v-col>
            <v-col xs="6" class="d-flex justify-end">
               <v-btn>Register</v-btn>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-form>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```

The result of the above code is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexboxes.

```
<div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between">
    <div>
        <v-btn type='submit' class='primary'>Login</v-btn>
    </div>
    <div>
        <v-btn class='ml-2'>Register</v-btn>
    </div>
```

For more on flexboxes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your buttons in a `div` and set it to `display:flex`. Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/DavidGolodetsky/pen/VwebZOM). If you need both buttons to be on the right side replace `justify-space-between` with `flex-end`